# Exporting chat history for Skype 8 and UWP

Tags: sqlite, message, archive, history, skype

I'm using both Skype 8.40.0.70 and Skype UWP on Windows 10.

As far as I know for Skype 8.40.0.70 it is no more possible to extract the chat history. Is that correct? At least I did not find any solution.

For Skype UWP I was able to get s4l-live%username.db file with the chat logs inside. Is it possible to extract csv or txt log files from this .db file? Unfortunately, SkypeLogViewer is not able to open the file. Or can csv or txt chat history files exported in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SQLite Browser to read the DB-File.
Not sure if you can read the messages, but it is possible to open the file.